# Twitter Login for Android app

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

can any one tell me the proper steps to perform the Open Auth for twitter login from my Android app? and one more thing is it posible to perform the login authentication of the twitter account without gng to the Twitter Login Page from my APP?

Idea is using the twitter account for loging in to my android APP (Authentication) ?

i hav tried it but it is gng to the twitter webview for the authentication without typing the username and password in my app?

so pls help me ! thanks in advance !!

Comment: Hi, How did you manage to login with twitter without opening webview when the app is installed and logged in.

Answer (score 10):

**App Setup**

```
Create App here https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps/create

Add Callback URLs to twittersdk:// (For Android SDK)

From App Details goto Keys and tokens and add in res/values/strings.xml

<string name="twitter_api_key">REPLACE_KEY</string>
<string name="twitter_api_secret">REPLACE_SECRET</string>

From App Details goto Permissions -> Edit

Access permission -> Read, write, and Direct Messages
Additional permissions -> Check to true (Request email address from users)
Save
```

**Add INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Add twitter SDK dependency to build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.1'
}
```

**In Activity**

```
private TwitterAuthClient twitterAuthClient;

Custom Button Click

TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
    .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
    .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_key), getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_api_secret)))
    .debug(true)
    .build();
Twitter.initialize(config);

twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

if (twitterSession == null) {
    twitterAuthClient.authorize(this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            TwitterSession twitterSession = result.data;
            getTwitterData(twitterSession);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Log.e("Twitter", "Failed to authenticate user " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
} else {
    getTwitterData(twitterSession);
}

private void getTwitterData(final TwitterSession twitterSession) {
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = new TwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
    final Call<User> getUserCall = twitterApiClient.getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true, false, true);
    getUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> result) {

            String socialId = "", firstName = "", lastName = "", gender = "", birthday = "", email = "", picture = "";

            User user = result.data;
            socialId = user.idStr;
            email = user.email;
            /*picture = user.profileImageUrlHttps.replace("_normal", "");
            firstName = user.name;
            lastName = user.screenName;*/

            try {
                firstName = user.name.split(" ")[0];
                lastName = user.name.split(" ")[1];
            } catch (Exception e) {
                firstName = user.name;
                lastName = "";
            }

            Log.e("Twitter", "SocialId: " + socialId + "\tFirstName: " + firstName + "\tLastName: " + lastName + "\tEmail: " + email);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.e("Twitter", "Failed to get user data " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (twitterAuthClient != null) {
        twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any new solution? This method is old now we cannot get any dependencies and twitter docs is very confusing. I want to use twitter sign in into my app please help...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `Twitter OAuth` for the purpose of Authentication for your App.
  The Example of `twitter OAuth` is described [**`here`**](http://honza.ca/2010/09/how-to-use-twitter-oauth-on-android)

Comment: Try adding some details that explain the answer here on SO instead of just pointing me to some URL.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It helps me for Twitter integration in android application.

This is offical Twitter Kit for Android(Twitter SDK)

check this link https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation

```
dependencies {
// Include all the Twitter APIs
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
// (Optional) Monetize using mopub
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
 }

public class CustomApplication {
  public void onCreate() {
   TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
       .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
       .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY",   "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
    .debug(true)
 .build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
}
}
```

Inside your layout, add a Login button with the following code:

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
 android:id="@+id/login_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In the Activity

```
loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
 @Override
 public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
    // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
 }

 @Override
 public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
     // Do something on failure
  }
 });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,   Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  // Pass the activity result to the login button.
  loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```